# How are spoiler questions to be handled?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I've got a question I was planning to ask. However, the title of the question:

> Why did Ned not tell Catelyn the truth about Jon?

Is a spoiler in and of itself. I'm not sure there's a way to frame that tile any better to make it not a spoiler. What's the proper way to address this on the site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the policy for spoilers?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) (also, your proposed question itself would be a duplicate of [Why did Eddard Stark keep Catelyn in the dark?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133204/why-did-eddard-stark-keep-catelyn-in-the-dark))

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Yeah, I figured one had been asked, but before I searched I figured I'd ask how they should be dealt with. Should have searched meta for this question too. :( lol

Comment: Per the dupe above; "**Avoid spoilers completely in the title**"

Comment: That particular title is not a spoiler at all, Ned kept Jon's mother a secret from *everybody* not just Cat.